# component.set('v.options') not working for lightning combobox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, selectoption, lightning-combobox

I am trying to set the options of a lightning combobox component dynamically by using `component.set('v.options', myOptions)` as was the case for the now deprecated `ui:inputSelect` but it seems not to be working. Is this no longer supported for the combobox?

Markup

```
<aura:attribute name="myVariable" type="Map" default="{val1:'', val2:''}" />
<aura:attribute name="myOptions" type="List" default="[{label: 'Option 1', value: 'option_1'}, {label: 'Option 2', value: 'option_2'}]" />

<lightning:combobox aura:id="required_input"
    required="true" placeholder="-- Select --" />
```

Controller

```
let inputCmp = component.find('required_input');
if (inputCmp) {
    inputCmp.set('v.label', 'testLabel');
    inputCmp.set('v.value', component.getReference('v.myVariable.val2'));
    inputCmp.set('v.options', component.getReference('v.myOptions'));
}
```

The options are not being displayed in the component.

Comment: can you add the relevant code here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set options values by using options property of combobox

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'New', 'value': 'new'},
    {'label': 'In Progress', 'value': 'inProgress'},
    {'label': 'Finished', 'value': 'finished'},
    ]"/>

    <lightning:combobox name="progress" label="Status" value="inProgress" placeholder="Select Progress" options="{! v.options }" onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: I know of that way of setting the options. I was just inquiring if we can also set them dynamically by setting the `options` attribute of the combobox directly from the controller.

Comment: init: function (cmp) {
        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            var item = {
                "label": i + " Option",
                "value": i.toString()
            };
            items.push(item);
        }
        cmp.set("v.options", items);
    }

use above to set option from controller

Comment: What if I want to use another attribute besides `options` to populate the combobox?

Comment: @user73893 you can just specify a different attribute name, default values, etc.

Comment: @GibralterTop it is the specifying part that is proving to be the issue. I do not want to do so statically in the markup. I want to do so dynamically in the controller. Say I created another attribute called `myOptions2` and wanted to use it as the combobox options under certain conditions. I would just have to change this line `inputCmp.set('v.options', component.getReference('v.myOptions'));` to this line `inputCmp.set('v.options', component.getReference('v.myOptions2'));` But this isn't working. Do you see my point?